# 61:61: syntax error: Expected string but found end of script. (-2741)

Tags: javascript, atom-editor, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

I've made a working script to run in Adobe Illustrator CC 2017 using ESTK. The script seems fine and runs when installed in illustrator or from ESTK. I would like to make some updates and extend the functionality a little but find the Adobe text editor arduous at best. So I've installed Atom with process-palette as per the instructions here:

https://github.com/rjduran/adobe-scripting/

All seems fine until I come to run the script at which point I get the following error:

```
Executed : osascript -e 'tell application "Adobe Illustrator"' -e 'activate' -e 'do javascript "#include '/Volumes/GoogleDrive/Team Drives/Graphics - Production/In progress/London/Bob Haslett/AI scripts/4Print V2.0.jsx'"' -e 'end tell'
Returned with code 1
61:61: syntax error: Expected string but found end of script. (-2741)
```

At which point I'm out of my depth. Any help appreciated, thanks

Comment: That's an AppleScript error, not an ExtendScript error.  It's likely due to the fact that you're not escaping the spaces int he path to the .jsx file.

Comment: FWIW, I had a similar error with Photoshop and it was because the application name changed (for the `tell application` command) from "Adobe Photoshop CC 2017" to "Adobe Photoshop CC 2018" due to updates.

Comment: Ah great thanks, that seems to have done the trick